# When I try to start gnome-tweaks it return me application errors that I can not understand and the shell remains hanging

Tags: arch-linux, python, gnome

I'using Arch Linux with Linux 5.10.11 with GNOME 3.38.3 and when I try to start Tweaks from the menu, nothing happens. So, when I try to start gnome-tweaks from bash it returns me this error remaining in hang:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 30, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.main_box.set_mode_transition_type(Handy.LeafletModeTransitionType.SLIDE)
AttributeError: 'Leaflet' object has no attribute 'set_mode_transition_type'
```

To stop this tweak's session I return Ctrl-C. I already modified *#!/usr/bin/env python3* with *#!/usr/bin/python3* in */usr/bin/gnome-tweaks*.

Is there anyone who could tell me why these errors and why gnome-tweaks is not starting?

Comment: Changing your python path won't solve it. Gi (where Leaflet is imported from) isn't in python packages path. it is unde /usr/lib

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet is imported form the Handy module belonging to gi/respository. `set_mode_transition_type` is deprecated for Leaflet since version 0.0.12 according to https://valadoc.org/libhandy-0.0/Hdy.Leaflet.set_mode_transition_type.html

Try updating gtweak or downgrading Gi library.

A not so recommended workaround would be to change `set_mode_transition_type` to `set_transition_type` on your tweakview.py file (new method's name). Although it might break other stuff.

If shell keeps on hanging you should probably update `gnome-shell`. That update would probably fix the Gi version mismatch.

Comment: Can you tell me where can i discover the gtweak package for Arch Linux? I'm not discovering it searching on the internet... I tryied with tweak python's package but it didn't work because it not can find gtweak.app for example.

Comment: use "locate gtweaks" on your terminal to find it. It will probably be under /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gtweak

Comment: in python's import, "." means its a subfolder. so /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gtweak/app is what you are looking for